# Asset Swap Spreads

Tags: credit-risk, default-risk

This is John Hull's book `Options, Futures and Other Derivatives  9th` `Page 549`

The process of calculating the `Asset Swap Spreads.`

1. $1+V$ the discounted value of floating rate paying of `LIBOR+premium`
2. $B^*$ the discounted value of fixed rate paying
3. $B$ is the current value of fixed rate bond
4. $1$ is the current value of floating rate bond(value at par)

As my understanding, floating rate paying will spend $1$ to buy the floating rate bond and receive the money $B^*;$ and fixed rate paying will spend $B$ to buy the fixed rate bond and receive the money $1+V.$

So the relation should be
$$-1 + B^* = - B + (1+V),$$
something reverse from the following result, I must misunderstand somewhere?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The asset swap spread is a function of the riskiness of the bond.

> floating rate paying will spend 1 to buy the floating rate bond and receive the money $B^∗$;

If he is the floating rate payer he is short the floating bond, not long.

On the floating rate paying leg he pays $1$ and he receives $1 + V$ (PV of Libor + Spread). The fixed rate receiver (same person) is long the risky fixed rate bond which costs $B$ and its payments (risk free) are worth $B^*$. With this reasoning you can go directly to $V = B^* - B$ by the way (floating rate pay leg present value is $1+V-1 = V$, fixed rate receive leg market present value is $B^* - B$).

Pay $1 + B^*$

Receive $1 + V + B$

Just reorganize $1 + V = B^* + 1 - B$

Comment: sorry, floating rate payer will pay the floating rate to other one, he should long a floating rate bond to match the floating paying cash flow and receive the fixed rate cash flow from other one, how can he be a short of floating?

Comment: You are mixing an hypothetical hedge with the product structure while it is not necessary to understand the payoff; being the floating rate payer is equivalent to being short a floating bond and long a fixed rate bond.